# Im having difficulty figuring out how to set my embed thumbnail to a array how would I do this?

Tags: arrays

On set thumbnail how would I turn that into a array? Ive tried multiple different sites discord servers and people but none of them can help me.

```js
module.exports ={
name : 'rd',
aliases : ['rd'],
run : async(client, message) => {
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`LOVER OF ALL THAT IS FOOD`)
.setDescription('BROTHERS OF THE ANCIENTS SISTERS OF THE DESTRUCTORS')
.setColor('f5ad42')
.setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/gZlXGsc.png')

// message.channel.send()
// message.reply()

message.channel.send(embed)
}
}
```

Comment: The question isn't exactly clear. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Okay your question doesn't really makes sense but I get it.

I assume you want the value of thumbnails to be in an array.

Do the following:

```
  module.exports = {
    name: 'rd',
    aliases: ['rd'],
    run: async (client, message) => {

      const thumbnails = ["https://i.imgur.com/gZlXGsc.png","","","",] // add more links

      const random = thumbnails[Math.floor(Math.random() * thumbnails.length)] // randomises the amount of links inside the thumbnails array.

      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`LOVER OF ALL THAT IS FOOD`)
        .setDescription('BROTHERS OF THE ANCIENTS`enter code here` SISTERS OF THE DESTRUCTORS')
        .setColor('f5ad42')
        .setThumbnail(`${random}`)
      message.channel.send(embed)
    }
  }
```

Comment: hello sorry if i didnt define it correctly i have trouble with this sort of thing but when i set this up it gives me the error discord is not defined inside the line of code                                                         const embed = new Discord.MessagesEmbed

Comment: @IXL make sure your first line of code is `const Discord = require('discord.js')`.

Comment: thank you this worked sometimes i forget the simplest things

Comment: Appologies for not realising a simple mistake